# Not so global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, geolocation, global

Global variables don't change when passed through the function, why?

```
var userLat = 0;
var userLong = 0;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    userLat = position.coords.latitude;
    userLong = position.coords.longitude;
  });
}
$("#loc").html(userLat + "<br>" + userLong);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an asynchronous function (Just like an ajax call).
Technically `$("#loc").html(userLat + "<br>" + userLong);` is executed before the response is available.